# Getting real tired of the other players being cheeky

Tags: poker-night-2

I've been having quite a bit of trouble focusing on playing the game when I've got the other players at the table (and GLaDOS) throwing random cheeky remarks at me, such as GLaDOS constantly referring to me checking as "a sign of confusion", or the smug Sam claiming that folding suits me.

*And I've had just about enough of that.*

Worst part is, unlike the first game, there's no option to reduce the dialogue.

**Does this ever ease off? Do they ever stop acting so cheeky?**

Comment: ...isn't that kind of...the entire point of the game over some generic poker game? The characters' personalities?

Comment: S'pose so, but I could have sworn that even in the first Poker Night game it eased off later in my career. In this one, it's just annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first Poker Night at the Inventory had an option for the amount *Table Conversation* in the *Gameplay Options*. With it, you could control the amount of banter during the gameplay to either hear it all the time, or to concentrate on the game.

Unfortunately this option was not included in Poker Night 2. The *Gameplay Options* includes only *How to Play* -section. The amount of banter also seems to be comparable to the high option level of the first game.

Of course, these only control the *amount* of banter. The quality of it is unaffected by any options. There is a large selection of dialogues that can happen and the ones that you hear are selected largely at random.

This holds doubly true for the lines spoken as a reaction to the player actions, as these have never been limited by any option, happen most of the time and as far as I can tell, aren't affected by any gameplay decisions.

Comment: So the other players mocking me is also random as you have said?

Comment: Mostly, yes. They usually react to most things the player does. I do not belive any option or gameplay decision affects *how* they react. If you want, you can take it as them wanting to manipulate you into bad calls :)

Answer (score -1):

Much like the original Poker Night at the Inventory, there should be an option in the options menu to adjust the level of dialogue from gabby to the bare minimum. (though they'll still probably make fun of you a bit. It's what the game is about)

Comment: I don't think there was actually. So that would probably be out of the question.

Comment: And this has been confirmed. This answer is wrong, there is no such option in PN2. Sorry about that :(